# "Виртуозное владение конем" — правильно ли так говорить?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, значение-слов

*... у легендарных амазонок древности, прославившихся своим **виртуозным владением конем** и умением выпускать стрелы, оборачиваясь на лету.*
[**Ахалтекинская лошадь: полет небесного скакуна**](http://akhalteke-horse.blogspot.com.ee/2015/03/blog-post_29.html)

Великолепное владение шпагой или прекрасное владение словом — эти фразы, конечно, вполне понятны и корректны.

А грамотно ли словосочетание ***владение конем***?

Answer (score 2):

> А грамотно ли словосочетание **владение конем**?

У меня сомнений не вызывает. Во всяком случае оно повсеместно распространено в художественной и специальной литературе. [Вот пример](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=48IKAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%22&dq=%22%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOhJr10bfYAhXGUlAKHTUvAvA4FBDoAQhBMAY) из книги В.А. Марьяновского "Кантемировы" (серия "Мастера советского цирка", М.: Искусство, 1978.)

На всякий случай привожу цитату из упомянутой книги:

> Точный расчёт, глазомер, хладнокровие, абсолютное владение конем принесли успех — огромный угорь достался ему...

Добавлю также, что "владеть" в данном контексте означает "уметь искусно пользоваться", а не "обладать".

Comment: Пример недоступен. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте ссылку.

Comment: @Aer Странно, у меня ссылка работает. Сейчас перенесу часть цитаты в ответ.

Comment: ссылка-то работает, да цитата не показывается...

Comment: @Aer Тем более странно. У меня показывается. Ничего, я перенёс цитату в ответ.

Comment: Из Нацкорпуса: Бежал в сечь запорожскую, Владеть конем и саблей научился… [В. А. Гиляровский. Мои скитания (1927)]

Comment: А как же быть со значениями? В л а д е т ь:  4. **чем.** Уметь обращаться с каким-нибудь предметом, искусно действовать (книжн.). «Кинжалом я владею.» Пушкин. Владеть оружием. Владеть французским языком (свободно говорить, писать на французском языке). Владеть пером (уметь литературно излагать свои мысли). https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/760034. Владеть (владение) - **кем?** - конём.

Comment: По-моему, нет проблем: владеть — чем? — конем

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Очевидно, что в данном случае конь выступает в роли инструмента/приспособления. Хотя меня немного удивляет, что настолько распространённое в литературе выражение не отмечено известными мне словарями.

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю ориентироваться на 2 значение в современном БТСРЯ под ред. Кузнецова (фото ниже). Именно этот словарь использует gramota.ru. Значения из словаря Ушакова (30-40 годы) представляются мне менее современными.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На мой взгляд, в случае с конём 2-е значение несколько ближе, чем 4-е (пример "владеть классом" иллюстративен, как и пример с цирком от *grizzly*). Хотя, возможно, есть смысл при анализе фразы "владение конём" рассматривать оба значения. В этом и интерес.

EDIT: При всём этом, если взять полностью, то фраза "виртуозное владение конём" в статье (где упоминаются амазонки) подразумевает, скорее, 4-е значение.

Comment: Конь в данном контексте выступает как средство передвижения. "Владеть (уметь управлять) конем" не отличается от "владеть (уметь управлять) мотоциклом". Одушевленность коня игнорируется. "Владеть конем и саблей..."(Гиляровский).

Comment: В принципе согласен. Внес изменения в EDIT. "Виртуозное владение конем", очевидно, вполне нормальная фраза. По началу смущал эпитет "виртуозный", теперь не смущает.